# Replicate Partition Over Network

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way, in Windows Server 2012 to replicate two same-size partitions over the network in real-time, preferably at driver level (not user-land)?

I am asking for two Hyper-V servers. There is not budget for a proper SAN, but there is budget to pick up an extra four-port 1g NIC for both servers (and connect them directly to one another). We only need one copy of each VM running at a time, so synchronous writes to the same file don't need to be supported.

Essentially the servers would work on their local copy of the partition, and replicate the changes remotely in real-time a la RAID-1 (both servers are running four-HDD RAID-10). Is there a protocol / procedure for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Hyper-V Replica for this.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134172.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware if this thanks to running client hyper-v in the testing environment (Win10). Thought fail-over was the only missing feature.

Comment: Glad to help...